# "Set down under my bedclothes"

Tags: meaning-in-context, sit-set

> Certainly I was now well awake; my body had veered round for the last time and the good angel of certainty had made all the surrounding objects stand still, ***had set me down under my bedclothes***, in my bedroom.

Could you help me understand this sentence? I searched *set down* in Google but it didn't help. This is what I have found:

1. to cause to sit down
2. to suspend (a jockey) from racing
3. to cause or allow to get off a vehicle
4. to land (an airplane) on the ground or water

I thought *down under* might be the key but it turned out that it means Australia or New Zealand. So, I'm confused and hopefully, you can help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: My answer provides the meaning but without knowing who *me* is, it's hard to describe it exactly. Could be a narrating dog? Or a child?

Comment: Thank you for responding. No, it is neither a narrating dog nor a child. It's an adult man who is recalling his waking moments.

Comment: Then, the angel of certainty did it. It's an image.The angel of certainty is the subject of the sentence....I missed that the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usable examples of the two-word verb: to set something down or set down something [less usual]

- to set a/the baby down
- to set a/the book down
- to set a/the chair down.

To set an object or child or animal down. To no longer be holding it. To place it somewhere.

Some object has been placed on a surface. In your case, the bed.

- He set down his pen and looked up at me when I entered the room

under the bedclothes= under the bedclothes, which could be under the sheets, blankets and bedspread of a made bed.